# Missing OpenGLES.framework for Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

As stupid as this may sound, I can't find OpenGLES.framework in the existing frameworks list. Is there any way to recover the framework? Would reinstalling Xcode replace OpenGLES? I've searched Google up and down with no avail.

Comment: you mean you not see this framwork in BuildPhases/Librarie....path???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reinstall the iPhone SDK, it should reinstall the framework.

Comment: How do you get the iPhone SDK?  developer.apple.com seems to be implying the only way is through the xcode installer.  1.65GB downloaded and installed and I still don't have the opengles.framework.

Comment: Click on your project file in the Xcode navigator, then on the "Build Phases" tab.  Expand the "Link Binary with Libraries" section.  Click on the plus icon.  The dialog which appears will show you the frameworks available, including hard to find ones, like OpenGLES, which is really hard to find normally, since it's inside the Xcode bundle at: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework`

Comment: I found it there a short while ago but wasn't sure if that was just the official location of it.  Good to know.  Now I just need to see whether it's possible to use it when building on the command line.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I'd be willing to bet the `-framework OpenGLES` flag will be sufficient.